# SyntaxError: Expected Expression, got '<' , different results on different environments

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, iis

I have an ASP.Net NVC app running on three different environments:

1. IIS via VS2013 IDE (Win8.1 Pro)
2. IIS on a UAT server (Windows Server 2012)
3. IIS on a Production Server (Windows Server 2012R2)

Running from the IDE and on the UAT server, everything is working as expected on all different browsers.  Running on the Production server...after working as expected for many many months...today it started giving the "SyntaxError: Expected Expression, got '<'" error.

As a result, I have scripts and style sheets that are no longer loading properly, depending on the browser.

In Chrome, it is finding my scripts, but not my style sheet.
In FireFox, it is finding neither.

When inspecting the page in the Firefox Dev Tools, all the js and css files are giving status 302 and are being seen as html files.

The source code on all three are identical.

Are there differences in IIS that could be causing the differences in performance?

I realize this has been asked several times, but has anyone actually figured out a reason that this is happening and found a definitive solution?  If so, I have not been able to find it.

Comment: *all the js and css files are giving status 302 and are being seen as html files.* That seems like pretty significant defect to me. I'd try and investigate that further.

Comment: Are there url rewrite rules somewhere that could give incorrect results?

Comment: Elliott - Thank you for staing the obvious.

Comment: VDWWD - No rewrite rules.

Comment: I also to add that on my Galaxy Note8, in every browser (Chrome, Firefox, and the Samsung Browser) I am getting undesirable results.

Comment: There are considerably more handler mappings on the production IIS than the UAT IIS.  Could this be causing any issues?